# How to remove documents from multiple collections based on ID in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections; schema as follows-

```
posts
 - ID
 - author
 - title
 - content

user_posts
 - ID
 - post_id
 - user_id
```

In SQL I could delete an entry from two tables at a time like

```
DELETE posts, user_posts
FROM posts
INNER JOIN user_posts
ON posts.ID = user_posts.post_id
WHERE posts.ID = 102
```

How can I achieve above similar code for Mongodb? I know how to delete an entry from single collection. One solution is to perform remove operation one after the other using callbacks for the surety of successful operation but I want to remove documents from both collections *at a time*.
 I referred [this solution using meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35848207/removing-document-from-multiple-collections-in-mongodb-with-meteorjs) but I'm quite new to Mongo so I could'nt understand it. Whereas [this solution is for **all** the collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845339/how-to-remove-document-from-all-collections-in-mongo-database) present in the current database but I have only these two collections related to this operation others are unrelated. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this is simply not possible. In order to access two collections you'd have to use the aggregation framework which, however, cannot perform any data manipulations at this stage. Plus, the "at a time" requirement would require support for transactions which is only available in a beta version right now - so again, bad luck.

Bottom line is: Your suggested approach with the callback is the way to go.