# How to remove documents from multiple collections in one query in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

It‘s an old question from [How to remove documents from multiple collections based on ID in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112685/) 2 years old.

If there is a solution?

My scenario is :

```
Collection A:
_id,
name
Collection B:
_id,
name,
aId,
Collection C:
_id,
name,
bId,
```

```
A vs mutiple-B
B vs mutiple-C
```

I want if there is a single query to delete docs by aId: XXX.
such as:

```
db.B.find({"aID":XXX}).foreach(
   function(b) {
     db.B.find({"_id":b._id}).foreach(
        function(c) {
           db.C.remove(c._id)
         }
     db.B.remove(b._id)
   }
);

db.A.remove("_id":XXX)
```

But it is two querys, Is there a better way?

Comment: If you are looking for atomicity, you might try a multi-document transaction